# Proof of Picard's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2, (a,b)\in U,$ and let $F: U\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy a Lipschitz condition on $U.$ Then there exists $\delta > 0 $ so that the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = F(x,y)$ has a unique solution $y=f(x)$ with $f(a) = b,$ defined for all $x\in [a-\delta, a+\delta].$

Below is part of a proof of this theorem.

Observe that $y=f(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = F(x,y)$ with $f(a) = b$ iff $f(x)$ satisfies the equation $f(x) = b + \int_a^x F(t, f(t)) dt$ for all $x\in [a-\delta, a+\delta].$ Let $\ell$ be a Lipschitz constant for $F.$ Choose $r > 0 $ so that $\overline{B}((a,b),r)\subseteq U$ and let $k=\max_{(x,y)\in \overline{B}((a,b),r)} |F(x,y)|.$ Choose $\delta >0$ with $\delta < \frac{1}{\ell}$ small enough so that the rectangle $R=[a-\delta, a+\delta]\times [b-k\delta, b+k\delta]\subseteq B((a,b), r).$

> I have two main questions:

1. I do not know how to show that if $f(x)$ is a solution to the given differential equation with $f(a) = b,$ then the graph of $f$ must be contained in the rectangle $R$. Here, $\operatorname{Graph}(f) := \{(x,f(x)) : x\in [a-\delta, a+\delta]\}.$ I was thinking of using the Mean Value Theorem and considering when $x\in [a-\delta, a), x=a, x=[a, a+\delta).$ Suppose $x\in [a-\delta, a+\delta].$ If $x=a, (x,f(x))\in R.$ Otherwise, if $x \in [a-\delta, a), \exists c \in (x,a)$ so that $f(a) - f(x) = \delta f'(c) = \delta F(c,f(c)).$ If I could show that $(c,f(c)) \in \overline{B}((a,b),r)$ (that is, $\lVert(c,f(c)) - (a,b)\rVert\leq r$), then the definition of $k$ gives the result. And the case where $x\in (a, a+\delta]$ should be similar.
2. I'm also not sure how to verify that the set $X = \{f \in \overline{C}[a-\delta, a+\delta] \mid\operatorname{Graph}(f)\subseteq R\}$ is a closed subspace of the metric space $C[a-\delta, a+\delta]$ under the supremum metric. I know one way is to show that every sequence in $X$ converges in $X,$ but I'd have to show that the limit's graph is contained in $R,$ which doesn't seem that easy.

> I only request justification for the two claims above. I know the rest of the proof can be completed using the fact that $X$ is a closed subset of the complete metric space $C[a-\delta, a+\delta].$ Then we can define $G(f)(x) = \int_a^x F(t, f(t)) dt + b,$ has the property that $G(X)\subseteq X$ and that $c=\ell \delta < 1$ is a contraction constant for $G.$ Thus by the Banach fixed point theorem, $G$ has a unique fixed point, which is the unique solution  to the differential equation.

Comment: 1.) That the constant $k$ exists is no problem, and also that some (maximal) $\delta$ can be constructed? 2.) Is your question this: If a sequence $f_k$ is uniformly bounded and converges to $f$, then the limit $f$ also has the same bound?